# Ограничения параметров типа "where T : ???"

Tags: c#, наследование, constraints

Есть некоторый интерфейс, являющийся оберткой для неизвестных типов.
Как минимум он наследует `System.IEquatable<T>`, `System.IComparable<T>`.
Ниже пример:

```cs
public interface IValue<T> :
  System.IComparable<IValue<T>>
  where T : notnull {
  public T Value { get; }
}
```

Значениями `Value`, в том числе, могут быть "простые" базовые типы. Например `int`, `double` и т.п. Очевидно, что методы сравнения `CompareTo(T?)` и т.п. можно реализовать для всех Number-типов в абстрактом классе. Но так как тип неизвестен, компилятор выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
public abstract class AValueNumber<T> :
  IValue<T>
  where T : notnull {

  public T Value { get; private protected set; }

  public int CompareTo(IValue<T>? other) =>
    (other is AValueNumber<T> v)
      // Error csharp(CS0019) Оператор "<" невозможно применить к операнду типа "T" и "T".
      ? v.Value switch {
        var x when x < Value => 1,
        var x when x > Value => -1,
        _ => 0
        }
      : 1;
}
```

... Причем это касается всех операторов `+, -, <, >, ==`.

[dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dv5pUe)

Какое ограничение типа установить в `where T : ???` и как это исправить?

Comment: если ты говоришь, что точно реализует `System.IEquatable<T>`, `System.IComparable<T>`  то вместо операторов просто используй `Equals` и `CompareTo`

Comment: @Grundy Да, спасибо. Как раз сейчас это и сделал.

Comment: А также был такой вопрос: [Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1326696/186999) не уверен на сколько они дубликаты

Comment: @Grundy Попробовал INumber, работает. Но пока остановился на текущем варианте.

Comment: [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/).

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение установить `IComparable|IEquatable` и не использовать `+, -, <, >, ==`

```cs
public abstract class AValueNumber<T> :
  IValue<T>
  where T : System.IComparable<T>, System.IEquatable<T> {
  public T Value { get; private protected set; }

  public int CompareTo(IValue<T>? other) =>
    (other is AValueNumber<T> v)
      ? Value.CompareTo(v.Value)
      : /* -> ... */;
}

class ValueInt : AValueNumber<int> {}
```